# Delete a managed object if the associated managed object has no elements

Tags: core-data

I have 2 entities in Core Data:

```
- OperationCategory
- Operation
```

The `OperationCategory` has a to-many relationship to `Operation` called  `operations`

The `Operation` has to-one relationship to `OperationCategory` called `operationCategory`

The `operations` relationship delete rule is set to `Deny` as an `OperationCategory` should not be deleted if there are still `Operation`s connected to it

However if all the `Operation` items have been deleted the `OperationCategory` should be deleted automatically. Is there a smart way to do this or do I have to check the `operations` relationship with every save and delete it manually? Thanks for any input

Comment: I think you should do this through KVO. Listen for changes in operations and perform a delete when it reaches zero elements

Comment: like http://www.cimgf.com/2011/10/14/parent-watching-its-child/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement -[Operation prepareForDeletion] and tell the OperationCategory to delete itself if the Operation is the last one.

Comment: Yes this would be one way