# Core Data - Delete Object if failing validation before save

Tags: core-data

I have an `NSManagedObject` that, when I save my `NSManagedObjectContext`, I would like to delete itself if it fails validation, rather than just stopping my context from saving and throwing an error. This way my save can continue successfully.

I'd only like for this to happen during a save. I'm not sure if `validateForUpdate()` is the right place to do this. Is there an accepted convention for how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First, you are better off validating the data either in the UI or in the network layer rather than relying on the persistence layer to do the validation.  That will avoid this issue completely.

Having said that, you can run `-validateForUpdate` and `-validateForInsert` to insure that the object is valid before you call save.

You can also let the error fire and then unroll the error to find out which objects are invalid, delete them and then save again.

Both of those solutions are sloppy compared to properly validating the data before the save (UI or network layer).

Comment: Thank you. I am validating in the UI when relevant.
I'm trying to do this when I have an object with a to-many relationship and the last object is removed from the relationship. (I have a min count of 1) so that the object is deleted. I don't want to use cascade, because I only want it deleted if it has no remaining relationships.

Comment: You can delete the object when it has no related objects. [Delete a managed object if the associated managed object has no elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961331/delete-a-managed-object-if-the-associated-managed-object-has-no-elements/26962834#26962834)