# In one-to-many relationship, is there a delete rule to delete the owner when its last member is deleted?

Tags: core-data

I have a one-to-many relationship in Core Data. For example, A->B where A is a department, B is employees. A department can have many employees and one employee can only have one department.

I set A->(casacade)->B, so if I delete A, all Bs will be deleted.

On the contrary, I can also delete B. In a situation when I delete the last B, is there any delete rule so that A will get deleted automatically? Or I have to delete A programmatically? Anything I should be careful about?

Comment: I'm not a Core Data expert, but I believe that you can constrain the relationship to require a minimum number of Bs for each A, but it is up to you to detect through validation that we have entered an invalid state (because the last B was deleted) and take appropriate action. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH20-SW1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a managed object if the associated managed object has no elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961331/delete-a-managed-object-if-the-associated-managed-object-has-no-elements/26962834#26962834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our sample app for our book https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/ we show exactly this use case.

Basically what you want to do is override `prepareForDeletion` (it gets called when your object is deleted). There you want to check if the array or set of objects that are no deleted is empty or not:

Here a country's `prepareForDeletion` checks it's (parent) continent has any non-deleted countries left:

```
public override func prepareForDeletion() {
    guard let c = continent else { return }
    if c.countries.filter({ !$0.deleted }).isEmpty {
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it the responsibility of the continent to delete itself if the number of countries is 0? The countries shouldn't decide this.

Comment: Conceptually you’re right, but this is not a *delete rule* that already exists.